# Users withouth password (at least for login)

Tags: users, multiuser

I have a desktop pc with 3 users on it. (Linux Mint 17 Rafaela)
These 3 users are mine, I use this configuration to isolate my work files and settings from the university files and my personal stuff. The problem is that I'm tired of entering the same password again and again. I want to work withouth password, neither for login or executing programs.

How can I achieve it? I can't search it on google because all the results says the same. "You have to enable autologin", but the autologin only works for 1 account, and it forces me to always boot with the same account.

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: What display manager are you using? On Ubuntu, `lightdm` is pre-configured to support the `nopasswdlogin` group for PAM login authentication, but I'm not sure that `mdm` is (although it probably can be).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove their passwords since you want them to autologin. On terminal
`sudo passwd user1 -d` for all three of them. They will not have any password.

Also if your users has sudo privileges I assume they do then you need to

`user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` on sudoers file for three users

Comment: That will remove their password, but the display manager has to allow passwordless logins as well.

Comment: he will just hit <enter> on login

Comment: AND it might break a lot of things (apps) that expect a user to have a password. (as apposed to a system account that doesn't have a password).

Comment: I would be intrested to know if this works, in theory it should.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can. Linux is based on user separation, and users need a password to login most display managers (or other methods like SSH). I think GDM will allow passwordless logins (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=123116) but the users still need a password, and you will still have to enter it for some things (like keyring).

You might be better off using another means for separating  your "users" workflows. It would be interesting to see the results of Log out -> Swap ~/.config with ~/.config.school -> Login.

As a final solution you could try Bluetooth or USB based authentication.

https://wiki.debian.org/pamusb and https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/libpam-blue/

Both can be added to pam, and pam configured to allow (for example) a USB key present OR password.  Be aware that some things will still require a password.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in sshd config file with path /etc/ssh/sshd.config.
Find PermitEmptyPasswords in the file and change it to yes, and you can have user without login passwords, I don't think that will be good practice though .

chnage this

> PermitEmptyPasswords no

to

> PermitEmptyPasswords yes

Comment: It doesn't work, I think that is only for ssh connections